# Unity: Why does my animation only work sometimes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to transition into a scene with a fade in/fade out animation. Basically just changing the alpha value of an Image.

As reference: I followed the tutorial of Brackeys here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE9VOZivb3I - However it did not work for me.

So I tried to do step one which is blending into a scene when started on my own.

I set up a SceneLoader with an Image:
[image: SceneLoader in Hierarchy]

I animated the alpha value change for a StartScene animation and added the Controller to the Canvas:
[image: Animator on canvas]

The Animator looks as following:

[image: Animator setup]

It worked a few times but stopped working suddenly. I'm pretty sure I did not change settings of the object.
When I prefabed it and put it on other scenes, it also did not work accordingly.

I have multiple UI Elements in my scenes, so I put the SceneLoader at the very bottom of the Hierarchy.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not to use the canvas but the panel instead. You can create 3 animations in the panel, one for fading in, one for fading out, and one for idle ( with transparent panel). Once you have done this you can set the fade-in for the first state and add a transition for the idle one without conditions with "Has exit time" with the duration of your animation. Then you can set a transition from idle to fade-out with a trigger. In the code, you will simply  `animator.SetTrigger(fading);` and it should work like that. Remember to uncheck the loop in fading animations and check it in the idle one.

Comment: I kind of already do that. Instead of the panel, i change the images opacity. I use another canvas element for the other UI elements - could that be a problem? Can I use multiple canvas elements at the same time?

Comment: Instead of using multiple canvas use multiple Panels, it's way better and easier to manage. It should have no problems at all

Comment: I just built it like you explained. It's working fine now.